# How can I display the user's live wallpaper as background in my app?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am creating a lockscreen replacement app for Android and would like to incorporate the user's currently selected wallpaper as my app's background. This is pretty easy to do for static background images, but I am not sure how to get a live wallpaper into my app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy. Add the following items to your theme:

```
<style name="MyAwesomeTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Or.Some.Other.Theme">
    <!-- your other theme items... 

    <!-- ADD THESE -->
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

No other coding is necessary.

Comment: Waaat. That looks so easy. I'll give it a shot this evening. Thanks!

Comment: Worked! It even responds to my touch gestures. Very slick.

Comment: @ChristianGöllner How do i support wallpaper scroll on swipe left and right?